# Reading text from HTML iOS SDK

Tags: html, ios, sdk

I have a Label in my View. The Label's text must be the text on http://sample.com/file.html.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'load' the contents of the URL directly into an `NSString`:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample.com/file.html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

And then set the label's text accordingly!

Comment: What I was going for, forgot string had a URL loading method

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSData`'s

```
+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL
```

Then convert to a string with `NSString`'s

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: Do you have a full example?